# How to use ibm workload scheduler on bluemix?

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, websphere-liberty, workload-scheduler

I try to use IBM workload scheduler on bluemix, but I can't find good information about using this service.

My steps are follow :

1. Create new Process library
2. Create new Process
3. Add general information
4. Add trigger
5. Add restful step and add url in it.
   The URL reference to the existing Java liberty instance that already connected to the service.(add some secure headers in advanced options)
6. Then I try to test my job and just run it now.

But in the end I have error :

> AWKRST030E An error occurred establishing a connection to the remote service. The error message is "Connection timed out".

Maybe I don't  indicate some fields?

Can anybody explain how to schedule task from existing liberty instance using Restful step in bluemix workload scheduler? Or can offer another solution how to use this service?

P.S. the url that I paste full.

Comment: It looks due to a firewall between Workload Scheduler service and the Bluemix application.
Which Bluemix region are you using?

Comment: @FrancoMossotto we use IBM CIO US South region

Answer (score 0):

Workload Scheduler service and its default cloud agents are running on the cloud outside Bluemix regions.

When using dedicated Bluemix regions, if you want to schedule an API of your application running on Bluemix, you have two options:

1. Assure the Bluemix region firewall allows incoming connections from the Workload Scheduler server hosting your instance.
2. Instantiate and run in your region the Workload Scheduler docker image **ibm_wa_agent**. This image contains the Workload Scheduler agent and you can bind it to the service instance to automatically connect the agent to your instance. From network perspective this will only require the possibility to open https connections from the docker container to Workload Scheduler cloud.

More information about Workload Scheduler docker container are available at [Scheduling with IBM Containers for Bluemix](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/WorkloadScheduler/docker_image_workloadscheduler/wkldsched_getstarted.html)

Comment: It seems to me that this solution is not available for us, because we use Bluemix inside IBM and we don't have this docker in catalog. The problem , i think, in firewall, i can't connect to the existing Cloudant service using appropriate step in scheduler. When i add all credentials and press Test Connection button i receive message that connection are not available.

Comment: Docker agent should be the solution to use the service in your environment. We are checking and we will let you know via email.

Comment: Maxim, please contact Fabio Barillari on IBM email, he can assist on getting the docker agent on your region

Comment: Thank you very much